How to extend file size limit in databricks_workspace_file for workspace uploads?
I am encountering an issue with file uploads exceeding the 10 MB size limit while using databricks_workspace_file to create workspace files in Databricks. The error message I receive is as follows:
Error: cannot create workspace file: File size imported is (11396743 bytes), exceeded max size (10485760 bytes)

HCL was generated using terraform-provider-databricks_v1.51.0 exporter
Is there any way to configure the file size limit for workspace uploads in terraform-provider-databricks?
I manually uploaded the same file directly through the Databricks UI, and it worked fine without any issues.
